# How do I capture a Stealth Infiltrator?

Tags: world-war

I'm playing World War on the iPad and I'm stuck at one mission where I need to use a Stealth Infiltrator.

[image]

But I'm completely oblivious as to during what mission this unit is captured! So can anyone tell me what mission I have to do to get it?

You get bonus points if you can give me a list with all the lootable units!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealth Infiltrator Mission: Tab #5 - Capture Enemy Spies

http://worldwar.rockydogmedia.com/lootguide.php

Comment: Thanks! Here I was searching on tab 6, no wonder I didn't spot it!